# How to read data from csv file in tensorflow?

Tags: csv, tensorflow

I want to read data from csv file in tensorflow .So I've been trying out different ways of reading a CSV file with 2000 lines and each line with 93 features,and I hope to get one-hot value.

my dataset is like this:
[image]

the first column is data of 93 features,and the second column is labels of 16 one-hot .
this is my code

```html
import tensorflow as tf




# data_input = pd.read_csv('ans_string.csv')
# data_train = pd.read_csv('ans_result.csv')

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,93])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([93,16]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([16]))


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["dataset.csv"])

reader = tf.TextLineReader()

key,value = reader.read(filename_queue)

# _,csv_row = reader.read(filename_queue)
# data = tf.decode_csv(csv_row,record_fefaults = rDeraults)

record_defaults_key = [[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]]
record_defaults_value = [[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]]

list_result_key = tf.decode_csv(key,record_defaults = record_defaults_key)
list_result_value = tf.decode_csv(value,record_defaults = record_defaults_value)

features = tf.stack(list_result_key)
labels = tf.stack(list_result_value)


y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W)+b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,16])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y),reduction_indices=[1]))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    
    # something happened
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord = coord)

    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    for _ in range (1000): 
        example,label = sess.run([features,labels])
        print(sess.run(example,label))
        sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:example,y_:label})
   
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1),tf.argmax(y_,1))  
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))
    print(sess.run(accuracy.eval({x:example,y_:label})))
    
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

I want to train my model,but I got Error like this.
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Which line is the ValueError on?

Comment: print(accuracy.eval({x:list_result_key,y_:list_result_value}))

Comment: You might want to post the whole error message.

Comment: I have updated my question,give me some advice please.

Comment: The error says there's an encoding problem in the csv